# Legacy install failure - error while installing greenlet on python 3.9.10

Tags: python, python-venv, greenlets

I'm trying to install sqlalchemy, which requires the package greenlet to be installed. Can someone tell me what is producing the error?

I'm using Pycharm with venv environment, I have tried installing it with `--force` command but it gives the same error.
The pip version is 22.0.4, if I try installing it on pip version 21.3.1, it generates a different error log

My wheel is already up to date

Here's the error report =>

```
Collecting greenlet
  Downloading greenlet-1.1.2.tar.gz (91 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 91.2/91.2 KB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [72 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_contextvars.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_cpp.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_extension_interface.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_gc.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator_nested.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_leaks.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_stack_saved.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_throw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_tracing.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_weakref.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      running egg_info
      writing src\greenlet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\greenlet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\greenlet.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\greenlet.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\slp_platformselect.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_alpha_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_amd64_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_ios.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_csky_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_mips_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_aix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_linux.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_riscv_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_s390_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x32_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.asm -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.obj -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_msvc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_msvc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: greenlet
  Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for greenlet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      running install
      E:\Programming\flaskCRUD\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and ot
her standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_contextvars.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_cpp.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_extension_interface.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_gc.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator_nested.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_leaks.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_stack_saved.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_throw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_tracing.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_weakref.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      running egg_info
      writing src\greenlet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\greenlet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\greenlet.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\greenlet.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\slp_platformselect.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_alpha_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_amd64_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_ios.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_csky_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_mips_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_aix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_linux.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_riscv_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_s390_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x32_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.asm -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.obj -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_msvc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_msvc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension.c -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\greenlet\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> greenlet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: `     error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')`

Comment: what does it mean? Can you please elaborate

Comment: It doesn't recognize your version of Windows.

Comment: I tried installing it globally and it worked, doesn't work for virtual environment though. For now, I'll just inherit it from global packages

Comment: Got the same plat-name error on windows. I'm already installing globally though... Any idea?

Comment: did u resolve the error? please mention the solution if you hav